# How to use Laravel DB Eloquent with() and get only specific column (Nested Eager Loading Specific Columns)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**Eager Loading Multiple Relationships**

```
books = Book::with(['author', 'publisher'])->get();
```

**Nested Eager Loading**

```
$books = Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

**Eager Loading Specific Columns**

```
$books = Book::with('author:id,name,book_id')->get();
```

---

**How to Nested Eager Loading Specific Columns?**

---

I try this code below but seems not working properly.

```
$books = Book::with('author:id,name,book_id, author.contacts:id,name,author_id')->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make query cheap and fast, we should only fetch column that we need. And for any reason, eager loading is good because we only retrieve data once instead of using foreach.

```
$data = Podcast::with(["comments" => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'podcast_id', 'comment', 'user_id');
    },"comments.users" => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'name');
    },"likes" => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id','podcast_id', 'count');
    }])->get(['id', 'title', 'author']);
```

Don't forget to `select 'id'` on Podcast model because it used to be primary key.
Also, don't forget to `select 'podcast_id'` on Comment model because it used to be foreign key.

Even if Comment belongs to many User, you still can fetch it as long as you `select 'user_id'` on Comment model.